# How to select and threshold x% of values from a multi-dim NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, data-processing

I have a multi-dimensional NumPy array with the shape `(32, 128, 128)`. For each entry in this array (which is of shape `(128, 128)`, I would like to check if 80% of the values present inside it are greater than a threshold, say 0.5.

Currently, I am doing something like so:

```py
for entry in entries: # entries: (32, 128, 128)
    raveled = np.ravel(entry) # entry: (128, 128)
    total_sum = (raveled > 0.5).sum()
    proportion = total_sum/len(raveled)

    if proportion > 0.8:
        ...
```

I cannot seem to figure out an efficient way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's an 'entry'?  What's inside or outside?

Comment: An entry is an array of shape (128, 128). The array is composed of floats drawn from a normal distribution with 0 mean and unit variance.

Comment: `arr>0.5` creates a boolean array with the same shape.  `np.sum` can be used to count the number of 'True/1' values.  `np.sum` (and similar `ufunc` take an `axis` tuple to specify summing on one or more of the dimensions.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I have also added what I just tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x =  np.random.rand(32, 128, 128)
#check 80%
np.sum(x > 0.5, axis = (1, 2)) > 0.8 * 128 * 128
```

`x > 0.5` will return True/False boolean for all values `(32 * 128 * 128)`. After that we are summing over 1st and 2nd axis `(128 * 128)` to extract the total number of True values i.e. where the conditions are met for all 32 arrays and checking whether the number is more than `80%`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you make the example a bit more comprehensive by adding comments? Might be helpful for other readers.